# Печать и снимок объекта

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Есть объект с идентификатором `.discussions` и кнопка

```
<div class="discussions">
   Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
</div>

<button>Печать</button> <button>Снимок</button>
```

Какими методами можно отдать на печать объект или сделать его снимок и отдать на скачивание?

Comment: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255291/print-the-contents-of-a-div